# Website URL directs to /wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url, redirect

I purchased domain designbids.co to for my wordpress site. Hosting is by godaddy. But due to some errors in configuration, designbids.co doesnt open my website, designbids.co/wordpress does.
For a quick solution, I redirected my other domain designbids.in to designbids.co/wordpress which opens my website fine but I didnt want the redirection to show. 
For this, I used this masking technique on godaddy but redirection with masking makes mobile optimization goes bad. It basically shows the desktop version on mobiles.
Currently, I have configured redirection without masking. So when I enter designbids.in, I can see it redirect to Designbids.in/wordpress.

Question: Is there any way that I can move my files out of the wordpress folder to solve this /wordpress problem? What is the safest way to get rid of this sort of redirection without messing with mobile optimization?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you running your web server? More information about how you run your server is necessary to answer this fully.

Comment: Is WordPress installed in your web root, or in a wordpress directory in your web root?

Comment: @mtinsley wordpress directory in root. We go httpdocs>wordpress>wp-content>themes> so on

Answer (score 0):

In your wordpress database look for the table wp_options there you will see 2 rows with option_name "siteurl" and "home" update those to not have /wordpress on the url

Comment: Thats it? Is this a safe/ recommended method for this sort of problem?

Comment: yes that is where your wordpress install configurations get saved, more than likely in your development environment you used /wordpress and when moved to production it was not updated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to have your WordPress site live at the root of your domain and not in the `/wordpress` folder, follow these steps:

- Log into WordPress as admin and go to the admin dashboard (`/wordpress/wp-admin/`)
- Go to `Settings` >> `General`
- Change the `WordPress Address` and `Site Address` to http://designbids.co
- **It is important to do the previous step first!!**
- After changing the URL in your WP Options, move ALL of the files and folders from the `/wordpress` directory on your site to the `/` directory.

Now your site will be served from designbids.co and not designbids.co/wordpress.

Comment: Are the instructions same if i want the URL to be designbids.in? Just change the address in the third step?

Comment: Does this solution work when my site in not in root but in wordpress directory? Thanks

Comment: These instructions are to move your site from `/wordpress` to `/`.  It tells how to tell WordPress the URL and move the actual WP files.  Since the WP files are actually on designbids.co it moves them there but should fix the cloaking from designbids.in too.

Comment: Thanks @drew010 . I will give this a try in the morning. Thanks.